# MySql Pivot only returning half the columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I i've table  data like this

```
table name = tbl_fgm_career

+------+-------+------+
| name | value | year |
+------+-------+------+
| a1   | 12    | 1970 |
| a2   | 56    | 1970 |
| a1   | 65    | 1971 |
| b7   | 555   | 1971 |
| .    | .     | .    |
| .    | .     | .    |
| .    | .     | .    |
| ab2  | 890   | 2019 |
+------+-------+------+
```

And I wrote this Procedure to convert Year values to Columns

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pivot_question`()
BEGIN
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT("SUM(IF(year='", year, "',value ,0)) AS '", year, "'"), "\n"
      ) INTO @answers
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT year FROM tbl_fgm_career
    ) A;

    SET @query := 
      CONCAT(
        'SELECT name, ', @answers, 
        ' FROM tbl_fgm_career  GROUP BY name'
      );

    PREPARE statement FROM @query;
    EXECUTE statement;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I had total 50 years (1970-2019). But when call this procedure I'm only getting till 1994. If I changed order by for year to DESC then I'm getting columns from (2019 to 1995)

How to Solve this problem.

Comment: Are you aware of group_concat default size limit? Is there a possibility you may have burst it?

Comment: @P.Salmon You're life saver man. Post this as answer and I'm happy to accept it. ```SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;``` Iused this and voila my script is working

Comment: if Salmon does not answer it, you can answer your own question and accept the answer. It will make it easier for other people encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maximum default size for GROUP_CONCAT is 1024. That's why I'm getting few columns.

I used `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` and my problem was solved.

Credits: @P.Salmon